# Store and work with a big .xls | local db?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, dataset

I am trying to write a program in c# where I want to modify an excel sheet with 570.000 rows ( and 10 columns). I need to delete some of the columns and calculate with others. 
I already tried to work a little bit with a mysql server but is this recommend for this local program?

Now I am wondering what's the best way to work with this huge dataset. Is it recommended to copy data in a sql db, or are there any better ways to use a database locally (like the dataset class)?

I am really thankful for any advice.

Comment: Really depends on what your are after. For local use just decode the file and load it. Do whatever and overwrite it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to narrow it down. As it is is based on opinions and this is not welcomed on Stackoverflow forum. Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic However, all depends on what you need to do in the future with those data and how you will updated them. SQL, mysql, and other DB they all can be used for such job.

Comment: I will try to specific my problem a little bit better:
First of all i have to go through each row and sum a specific column over the hole sheet. Afterwards i get a value which i again compare with every row and maybe delete the row after the comparison. This routine i will execute about 5 times with different comparisons for each step. The deleted row I don't need anymore and the easiest way would be to delete the complete row.
I need this db just local and I also don't need to save it in a file. The only demand is to calculate the values in acceptable period of time.

Comment: does http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 SQL Server Express meet your needs?  It will be easier than MySQL for C#/Excel interoperability.